# Datetime fails when setting astype, date mangled

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I am importing a csv of 20 variables and 1500 records. There are 5 date columns that are in UK date format dd/mm/yyyy , and import as .str
I need to be be able to subract one date from another.They are hsopital admissions, - I need to subtract discharge date from admission date to get length of stay. 
I have has a number of problems.
To illustrate I have used 2 columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
```

import .csv

```
df = pd.read_csv("/Users........csv", usecols = ['ADMIDATE', 'DISDATE'])
```

```
df
    ADMIDATE    DISDATE
0   04/02/2018  07/02/2018
1   25/07/2017  1801-01-01
2   28/06/2017  01/07/2017
3   22/06/2017  1801-01-01
4   11/12/2017  15/12/2017
... ... ...
1503    25/01/2019  27/01/2019
1504    31/08/2018  1801-01-01
1505    20/09/2018  05/11/2018
1506    28/09/2018  1801-01-01
1507    21/02/2019  24/02/2019
1508 rows × 2 columns
```

I removed about 100 records with a DISDATE of 1801-01-01, - these are likely bad data from the patient still being in hospital when the data was collected. 
To convert the dates to datetime, I have used .astype('datetime64[ns]')
This is because I didn't know how to use pd.to_datetime on multiple columns.

```
df[['ADMIDATE', 'DISDATE']] = df[['ADMIDATE', 'DISDATE']].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1399 entries, 0 to 1398
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------      --------------  -----         
 0   Unnamed: 0  1399 non-null   int64         
 1   ADMIDATE    1399 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 2   DISDATE     1391 non-null   datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), int64(1)
memory usage: 32.9 KB
```

So, the conversion appears to have worked. 
However on examining the data, ADMIDATE has become yyyy-mm-dd and DISDATE yyyy-dd-mm.

```
df.head(20)
    Unnamed: 0  ADMIDATE    DISDATE
0   0   2018-04-02  2018-07-02
1   2   2017-06-28  2017-01-07
2   4   2017-11-12  2017-12-15
3   5   2017-09-04  2017-12-04
4   6   2017-05-30  2017-01-06
5   7   2017-02-08  2017-07-08
6   8   2017-11-17  2017-11-18
7   9   2018-03-14  2018-03-20
8   10  2017-04-26  2017-03-05
9   11  2017-05-16  2017-05-17
10  12  2018-01-17  2018-01-19
11  13  2017-12-18  2017-12-20
12  14  2017-02-10  2017-04-10
13  16  2017-03-30  2017-07-04
14  17  2017-01-12  2017-12-18
15  18  2017-12-07  2017-07-14
16  19  2017-05-04  2017-08-04
17  20  2017-10-30  2017-01-11
18  21  2017-06-19  2017-06-22
19  22  2017-04-05  2017-08-05
```

So when I subract the ADMIDATE from the DISDATE I am getting negative values.

```
df['DISDATE'] - df['ADMIDATE']
0        91 days
1      -172 days
2        33 days
3        91 days
4      -144 days
          ...   
1394    188 days
1395   -291 days
1396      2 days
1397   -132 days
1398      3 days
Length: 1399, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I would like a method that works on all my date columns, keeps the UK format and allows me to do basic operations on the date fields.

After the suggestions from @code-different which seems very sensible below

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
```

The format is unchanged despite dayfirst=True.

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1399 entries, 0 to 1398
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------      --------------  -----         
 0   Unnamed: 0  1399 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 1   ADMIDATE    1399 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 2   DISDATE     1391 non-null   datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](3)
memory usage: 32.9 KB
```

```
df.head()

Unnamed: 0  ADMIDATE    DISDATE
0   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000   2018-04-02  2018-07-02
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002   2017-06-28  2017-01-07
2   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000004   2017-11-12  2017-12-15
3   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000005   2017-09-04  2017-12-04
4   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000006   2017-05-30  2017-01-06
```

I have also tried `format='%d%m%Y'` and still the year is first. Would datetime.strptime be any good?.

Comment: Look at the `pd.to_datetime` with format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just tell `pandas.to_datetime` to use a specific and adequate format, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ADMIDATE': ['04/02/2018', '25/07/2017', 
                                '28/06/2017', '22/06/2017', '11/12/2017'],
                   'DISDATE': ['07/02/2018', '1801-01-01', 
                               '01/07/2017', '1801-01-01', '15/12/2017']}).replace({'1801-01-01': np.datetime64('NaT')})


for col in ['ADMIDATE', 'DISDATE']:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format='%d/%m/%Y')

# df
#     ADMIDATE    DISDATE
# 0 2018-02-04 2018-02-07
# 1 2017-07-25        NaT
# 2 2017-06-28 2017-07-01
# 3 2017-06-22        NaT
# 4 2017-12-11 2017-12-15    

#   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype         
# ---  ------    --------------  -----         
#  0   ADMIDATE  5 non-null      datetime64[ns]
#  1   DISDATE   3 non-null      datetime64[ns]
# dtypes: datetime64[ns](2)
```

Note: replace `'1801-01-01'` with `np.datetime64('NaT')` so you don't have to ignore errors when calling `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: Thanks, this has worked as far as the calculation and is consistent. However I don't understand why the year comes first despite the format asking for **%d%m%Y** ?

Comment: @capnahab: the format code refers to the input - the output you see is just the default way `pandas` displays dates.

Answer (score 1):

`to_datetime` is the function you want. It does not support multiple columns so you just loop over the columns one by one. The strings are in UK format (day-first) so you simply tell `to_datetime` that:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', usecols = ['ADMIDATE','DISDATE']).replace({'1801-01-01': pd.NA})

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
```

`astype('datetime64[ns]')` is too inflexible for what you need.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly loops over the columns and converts the string dates to datetime format,  but the format does not change to day first.